# how do I delete multiple histories in web app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, web, browser-history

I'd like to remove multiple browser history at once.

Suppose your app has a `blog-writing` task which takes multiple steps/screens/browser history to finish.

When a user completes the blog-writing task, you want to delete the whole writing-related browser histories because when he clicks back button, you don't want him to see his editing screen again.

Conceptually, I'm wondering if there's a way to group multiple browser histories as a task (blog writing task), then kill the histories related to the task.

Then it doesn't matter how many steps you take to perform a task, you can just drop the task when needed.

Can this be done in web environment?

Comment: history.go(0-(history.length-1)) will clear everything. you should memorize history.length onload and then you can go back "not all the way".

Comment: But i guess, clearing history object will _not_ help in disabling back buttons immediately.

Comment: currently, I'm thinking 'keeping the counter' in backbone router. and goBack(counter) when task is done. Haven't implemented it though.